# .filter() not filtering the items from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have this array of data in Javascript:

```
// console.log(currentMembers.members)
// *************************
// CURRENT MEMBERS
// *************************
// [
//   new ObjectId("62385d8caee17d13a1762b39"),
//   new ObjectId("6238a480170aff10d16ccd86"),
//   new ObjectId("6238a480170aff10d16ccd86"),
//   new ObjectId("6238a608170aff10d16ccd89")
// ]
```

I want to remove from the array one value that matches the variable "memberToRemove". So .filter() should be enough to perform this but it doesn't and I'm lost.

```
try {
    const newListofMembers = currentMembers.members.filter(
      member => member._id !== memberToRemove
    );
const updatedMembers = await Group.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: groupId },
    { members: newListofMembers }
    );
    console.log('Users successfully updated.');
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, members: newListofMembers });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  }
```

When I perform this action nothing happens, when I console.log(newListOfMembers) the filter doesn't seem to work at all, it ignores the member => member !== memberToRemove. The member to remove is 6238a608170aff10d16ccd89.

Comment: Maybe `member => member._id !== new ObjectId(memberToRemove)`?

Comment: If i do that i get ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined

Comment: Have you ```console.log(member.__id)``` and ```console.log(memberToRemove)``` inside the filter function to verify that those 2 have the values you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest, you can change you filter into this `member => String(member._id) === memberToRemove`

But the right way is

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const { Types } = require('mongoose');

const newListofMembers = currentMembers.members.filter(
      member => !_.isEqual(member._id, Types.ObjectId(memberToRemove))
);
```

You can replace `member => !_.isEqual(member._id, Types.ObjectId(memberToRemove))` with `member => !_.isEqual(member, Types.ObjectId(memberToRemove))` or `!item.equals(memberToRemove)`

Comment: First example worked, second doesn't.

Comment: i just edited my answer xD

Comment: `ObjectId` has a `.equals` method, no need to pull in lodash here.

Comment: @CollinD thanks you! i'll update my answer

Comment: Why is it the right way?